Branching Information of SCIP Run
I'm working on a problem using Pyomo with SCIP as the solver.
I've noticed that sometimes the same instances are solved almost instantly, while other times they take significantly longer (with a difference of 1 or 2 orders of magnitude). I want to explore the branching procedure (or any other relevant information) in each of these cases to improve parameter tuning.
How can I access this information using Pyomo as the interface?
